# How to prove that $f$ is integrable if $\forall \epsilon, \ \exists$ partition $M\in [a,b]$ such that $U_f(M) - L_f(M)\lt\epsilon$?

Tags: calculus, integration, supremum-and-infimum

In order to let $f$ be integrable, its lower integral,$\underline{I}_a^b(f)$,  has to equal upper integrable, $\overline{I}_a^b(f)$. I suppose that we can claim that because  $\forall \epsilon, U_f(M) - L_f(M)\lt\epsilon$, $\ U_f(M) - L_f(M)=0$ would be the only solution since $\ U_f(M) - L_f(M)\ge 0$. So if $\ U_f(M) - L_f(M)=0$, $\underline{I}_a^b(f)$ has to be the greatest $L_f(M)$ and $\overline{I}_a^b(f)$ is the smallest $U_f(M)$. However I have a bit problem formalizing th proof and I am not sure which parts are wrong, so any thoughts would be greatly helpful.

Comment: In practice these partitions might get pretty exotic. What partition makes the upper and lower Riemann sums close when $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{100}\frac{1}{n}\sin nx$ ? This converges to a [sawtooth wave](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hypothesis does not allow you to conclude that $U_f(M) - L_f(M) < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ and $M$ fixed. Rather for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is a partition $M_\epsilon$ for which $U_f(M_{\epsilon}) - L_f(M_{\epsilon}) < \epsilon.$

Nevertheless this implies that the difference between upper and lower integrals can be squeezed between $0$ and any $\epsilon > 0$, hence equal to $0$.  The lower integral is the supremum of lower sums over all partitions and the upper integral is the infimum of upper sums over all partitions. Hence,

$$L_f(M_{\epsilon}) \leqslant \underline{I}_a^b(f) \leqslant \overline{I}_a^b(f) \leqslant U_f(M_{\epsilon}) \\ \implies  0 \leqslant \overline{I}_a^b(f) - \underline{I}_a^b(f) \leqslant U_f(M_{\epsilon}) - L_f(M_{\epsilon}) \leqslant \epsilon \\ \implies \overline{I}_a^b(f) = \underline{I}_a^b(f)
$$

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  One additional piece of the proof is that the lower integral is less than or equal to the upper integral. I'm sure you know this, but it follows because any upper sum is an upper bound for lower sums corresponding to any partition.